# Select all projects that have matching tags

Tags: sql, mysql, tags, left-join, join

I'm trying to find the most efficient way of dealing with this but I must tell you front-head I've made a mess of it. Looked around SO and found nothing of relevance so here it goes.

**How to select all projects that have similar tags to the desired project?**

Take this table for example:
<sub>(sql code to recreate tables bellow)</sub>

```
project 1 -> tagA | tagB | tagC
project 2 -> tagA | tagB
project 3 -> tagA
project 4 -> tagC
```

Selecting project 1 should return back all projects.
Selecting project 4 should only return project project 1

My query so far is pretty dependant of left joins and for sure there is a better way to do this:

```
SELECT all_tags.project_id, all_tags.tag_id, final.title, tag.tag
FROM projects AS p
LEFT JOIN projects_to_tags AS pt ON p.num = pt.project_id
LEFT JOIN projects_to_tags AS all_tags ON pt.tag_id = all_tags.tag_id
LEFT JOIN projects AS final ON all_tags.project_id = final.num
LEFT JOIN tags AS tag ON all_tags.tag_id = tag.tag_id
WHERE p.num = 4
GROUP BY final.num
```

---

Thank you all for the input. I though I'd share with you guys the average results of all the queries on a 100k projects database, 100k tags database with a 100k projects_to_tags relation. All queries were changed to ask for project_1.

The sweet and short:

```
0.0160 sec - OMG Ponies - Using JOINS  
0.0208 sec - jdelard  
0.2581 sec - OMG Ponies - Using EXISTS  
0.2777 sec - OMG Ponies - Using IN  
0.5295 sec - Emtucifor - updated query  
0.5088 sec - Emtucifor - first query
```

Thank you all very much for this. Gonna update ALL my queries accordingly.

**Here go all queries and respective MySQL EXPLAIN's along with time's**

```
===============================================================================================================================================
Emtucifor - updated query
===============================================================================================================================================
Showing rows 0 - 1 (2 total, Query took 0.5295 sec)
SELECT * 
FROM projects AS L
WHERE L.num !=1-- instead of <> PT2.project_id inside

AND EXISTS (

SELECT 1 
FROM projects_to_tags PT
INNER JOIN projects_to_tags PT2 ON PT.tag_id = PT2.tag_id
WHERE L.num = PT.project_id
AND PT2.project_id =1
)
LIMIT 0 , 30

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY L   ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    100000  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  PT2 ref project_id  project_id  4   const   1   Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  PT  ref project_id  project_id  8   test.L.num,test.PT2.tag_id  12000   Using index




===============================================================================================================================================
Emtucifor - first query
===============================================================================================================================================
Showing rows 0 - 1 (2 total, Query took 0.5088 sec)
SELECT * 
FROM projects AS L
WHERE 
EXISTS (

SELECT 1 
FROM projects_to_tags PT
INNER JOIN projects_to_tags PT2 ON PT.tag_id = PT2.tag_id
WHERE L.num = PT.project_id
AND PT2.project_id =1
AND PT2.project_id <> L.num
)
LIMIT 0 , 30

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY L   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    100000  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  PT2 ref project_id  project_id  4   const   1   Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  PT  ref project_id  project_id  8   test.L.num,test.PT2.tag_id  12000   Using where; Using index




===============================================================================================================================================
jdelard
===============================================================================================================================================
Showing rows 0 - 1 (2 total, Query took 0.0208 sec)
SELECT p.num, p.title
FROM projects_to_tags pt1, projects_to_tags pt2, projects p
WHERE pt1.project_id =1
AND pt2.project_id !=1
AND pt1.tag_id = pt2.tag_id
AND p.num = pt2.project_id
GROUP BY pt2.project_id
LIMIT 0 , 30

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  pt1 ref project_id  project_id  4   const   1   Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  pt2 index   project_id  project_id  8   NULL    75001   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  p   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   test.pt2.project_id 1    




===============================================================================================================================================
OMG Ponies - Using IN
===============================================================================================================================================
Showing rows 0 - 2 (3 total, Query took 0.2777 sec)
SELECT p . * 
FROM projects p
JOIN projects_to_tags pt ON pt.project_id = p.num
WHERE pt.tag_id
IN (

SELECT x.tag_id
FROM projects_to_tags x
WHERE x.project_id =1
)
LIMIT 0 , 30

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY pt  index   project_id  project_id  8   NULL    100001  Using where; Using index
1   PRIMARY p   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   test.pt.project_id  1    
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  x   ref project_id  project_id  8   const,func  12000   Using where; Using index




===============================================================================================================================================
OMG Ponies - Using EXISTS
===============================================================================================================================================
Showing rows 0 - 2 (3 total, Query took 0.2581 sec)
SELECT p . * 
FROM projects p
JOIN projects_to_tags pt ON pt.project_id = p.num
WHERE EXISTS (

SELECT NULL 
FROM projects_to_tags x
WHERE x.project_id = 1
AND x.tag_id = pt.tag_id
)
LIMIT 0 , 30




===============================================================================================================================================
OMG Ponies - Using JOINS
===============================================================================================================================================
Showing rows 0 - 2 (3 total, Query took 0.0160 sec)
SELECT DISTINCT p . * 
FROM projects p
JOIN projects_to_tags pt ON pt.project_id = p.num
JOIN projects_to_tags x ON x.tag_id = pt.tag_id
AND x.project_id = 1
LIMIT 0 , 30

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  x   ref project_id  project_id  4   const   1   Using index; Using temporary
1   SIMPLE  pt  index   project_id  project_id  8   NULL    75001   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  p   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   test.pt.project_id  1
```

---

SQL code to copy/paste and mess around.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects` (
  `num` int(2) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`num`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


INSERT INTO `projects` (`num`, `title`) VALUES(1, 'project 1'),(2, 'project 2'),(3, 'project 3'),(4, 'project 4');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects_to_tags` (
  `project_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  KEY `project_id` (`project_id`,`tag_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `projects_to_tags` (`project_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES(1, 1),(1, 2),(1, 3),(2, 1),(2, 2),(3, 1),(4, 3);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `tag_id` int(2) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `tag` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`tag_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tag` (`tag`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;


INSERT INTO `tags` (`tag_id`, `tag`) VALUES(1, 'tag a'),(2, 'tag b'),(3, 'tag c');
```

Comment: @Emtucifor thank you very much! This question was great fun.

Comment: @OMG Ponies your JOINS make MySQL pump! Thank you!

Comment: @jdelard great SQL! I found it very easy to read and could tell in a snap that it would be very efficient-wise. OMG Ponies, however, beat you by a few microseconds nonetheless. Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you include my updated query? I'd love to know how it stacks up. Which of OMG Ponies' queries did you settle on?

Comment: @Emtucifor tested both! ;) You can check the results in my question page that has been updated to reflect the tests, the results of `explain` and the avg result of 100 hits for each query.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Thanks! Just keep in mind that as your data grows, the results might change and a different query become more efficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In any of the following cases, if you don't know the `PROJECT.num`/`PROJECT_TO_TAGS.project_id`, you'll have to join to the `PROJECTS` table to get the id value for finding out what tags it has associated.

### Using IN

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM PROJECTS p
  JOIN PROJECTS_TO_TAGS pt ON pt.project_id = p.num
 WHERE pt.tag_id IN (SELECT x.tag_id
                       FROM PROJECTS_TO_TAGS x
                      WHERE x.project_id = 4)
```

### Using EXISTS

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM PROJECTS p
  JOIN PROJECTS_TO_TAGS pt ON pt.project_id = p.num
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM PROJECTS_TO_TAGS x
                WHERE x.project_id = 4
                  AND x.tag_id = pt.tag_id)
```

### Using JOINS (this the most efficient one!)

The `DISTINCT` is necessary because JOINs risk duplicated data turning up in the resultset...

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
  FROM PROJECTS p
  JOIN PROJECTS_TO_TAGS pt ON pt.project_id = p.num
  JOIN PROJECTS_TO_TAGS x ON x.tag_id = pt.tag_id
                         AND x.project_id = 4
```

Comment: thank you very much! Your SQL looks beautiful! Nevertheless all 3 possibilities require a full table scan. I was pretty much trying to avoid that (which I do on my spaghetti-looking SQL code)

Answer (score 4):

How about... (example for project 1)

```
SELECT p.num, p.title
FROM projects_to_tags pt1, projects_to_tags pt2, projects p
where pt1.project_id = 1 and 
      pt2.project_id != 1 and 
      pt1.tag_id = pt2.tag_id and 
      p.num = pt2.project_id 
group by pt2.project_id
```

And maybe add a separate index for tag_id in projects_to_tags so you can use it alone, instead of the composite. No more type ALL. (Table Scan) 
Replacing both **1** with **4** give also the desired results.

Comment: just perfect. Simple, elegant and very performance wise solution. Love it. Thanks!

Comment: Please explain how MySql does a group by with columns in the select list that have no aggregate on them?

Comment: Also, I didn't know anyone was still writing non-ANSI joins... in 2010!?!?! :)

Comment: @Emtucifor: This is ANSI-89 join syntax, but I agree that theses days it should be ANSI-92 syntax.  Also, "hidden" columns in the `GROUP BY` is documented behavior: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: @OMG Ponies - interesting. It's like a default First() or Any() aggregate.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this... ?

```
SELECT *
FROM projects AS L
WHERE
   EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM
         projects_to_tags PT
         INNER JOIN projects_to_tags PT2 ON PT.tag_id = PT2.tag_id
      WHERE
         L.num = PT.project_id
         AND PT2.project_id = 4
         AND PT2.project_id <> L.num
   )
```

That's 2 seeks and a scan.

**UPDATE**

Taking a page from jdelard's book, one tiny modification switches my query to outperform his (of course I'm doing this on SQL Server meaning I took out his GROUP BY and put in a DISTINCT, so YMMV on MySQL):

```
SELECT *
FROM projects AS L
WHERE
   L.num != 4 -- instead of <> PT2.project_id inside
   AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM
         projects_to_tags PT
         INNER JOIN projects_to_tags PT2 ON PT.tag_id = PT2.tag_id
      WHERE
         L.num = PT.project_id
         AND PT2.project_id = 4
   )
```

The improvement over his query comes from not doing a DISTINCT or aggregate, and using a semi join instead of a complete join so not every row has to be joined. Otherwise, semantically they are largely the same.

I will have to remember jdelard's trick as it is a very useful tool. For some reason the query engine was not smart enough to compute that given {a = 4, a != b} then {b != 4}.

Comment: very nice, thanks! The full table scan put me a bit off and the projects table can (and will) grow to a pretty extensive size. I specially like non-showing the original project that, even though was not asked, was the intention. Thanks!