# Mysql related articles

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a query return 3 articles related to the one a user is reading. For this purpose I've made a tabel with a set of tags related to all articles (up to 5 tags pr. article).

- How do I construct my query the most effective way to return 3 related articles?
- Incase there is no related articles - how to return 3 random?

Here's what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `j_news` (
  `n_id` smallint(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `n_title` varchar(94) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `n_text` text COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=25 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `j_news_tags` (
  `nt_id` mediumint(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nt_news_id` mediumint(7) NOT NULL,
  `nt_tag` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`nt_id`),
  KEY `nt_news_id` (`nt_news_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are **really considering performance [I would suggest you read up this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581023/select-all-projects-that-have-matching-tags)** I had sometime ago. It deals with large databases and has benchmarks on different queries (all dealing with tags).

To shorten it out the SQL would be like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p . * 
FROM projects p
JOIN projects_to_tags pt ON pt.project_id = p.num
JOIN projects_to_tags x ON x.tag_id = pt.tag_id
AND x.project_id = x -- x is your project ID number
```

Comment: I have tried the following query-statement:

    $get_entries = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT n.n_id, n.n_title, n.n_text FROM j_news n JOIN j_news_tags nt ON nt.nt_news_id = n.n_id JOIN j_news_tags x ON x.nt_id = nt.nt_id AND x.nt_news_id = ".$news_id." LIMIT 0,3") or die(mysql_error());

Though it's not working as intended since it returns only the article the user is already viewing

I'm open for suggestions!

Thanks :- )

Comment: @kris in the linked question you will find code to recreate the tables  and the conditions of my example query. Then, adapting it to work on your tables should be pretty trivial.