# mysql query for related articles

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

- **Article** (idArticle)
- **ArticleTag** (idArticle, idTag)
- **Tag** (idTag)

I want to get all the articles that have the same tags as the article "5", i was trying like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Article.*
FROM Article
INNER JOIN ArticleTag ON Article.idArticle = ArticleTag.idArticle 
       AND ArticleTag.idArticle = "5"
WHERE 1 = 1
ORDER BY title
LIMIT 40
```

But it shows all the Articles and not the related ones.

Comment: can you post your table columns??

Comment: The `WHERE 1=1` is useless -- it'll be optimized out.

Comment: you.re right, 1=1 is useless... and the tables are just Article (idArticle), ArticleTag (idArticle, idTag), Tag (idTag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
select a.* from Article a
inner join ArticleTag at
  on at.idArticle = a.idArticle
where at.idTag in (select idTag from ArticleTag where idArticle =5)
```

or

```
select a.* from Article a
inner join ArticleTag at on at.idArticle= a.idArticle
inner join ArticleTag at2 on at2.idTag = a.idTag and at2.IdArticle! = at.idArticle
where at2.idArticle = 5
```

Comment: it works just like Brian's solution, the problem is performance... i waas wondering something using just JOINS

Comment: What about

    select a.* from Article a
    inner join ArticleTag at on at.idArticle= a.idArticle
    inner join ArticleTag at2 on at2.idTag = a.idTag and at2.IdArticle! = at.idArticle
    where at2.idArticle = 5

Comment: Almost there... i found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581023/select-all-projects-that-have-matching-tags i.ll check you as the correct answer for the effort, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Article.*
FROM Article
INNER JOIN ArticleTag ON Article.idArticle = ArticleTag.idArticle 
WHERE ArticleTag.idTag IN 
(SELECT ArticleTag.idTag FROM ArticleTag WHERE ArticleTag.idArticle = '5')
ORDER BY Article.title
LIMIT 40;
```

Comment: Yeah - was just fixing that when you commented

Comment: I changed the last ArticleTag.idTag for ArticleTag.idArticle... it works but it's too slow, when I run a EXPLAIN it says the index is ALL (really low performance)

Comment: The OP wanted articles with the same tags as those of article 5, not tag 5.

Comment: Yes, it's going to be slow. You're having to check every line against the list generated by the subquery. Linear searching at its finest.